# Basic algebra: Prove that an n-degree polynomial is expressible as the product of n binomials.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

*Using basic algebra, how does one prove that an n-degree polynomial is expressible as the product of $n$ binomials?*  Here I am allowing for binomials of the form $xb_i+\alpha_i=x0+1.$

This is something I **should** know like the back of my hand, but I don't.  The answer I am seeking is a *high school-level* demonstration.  I am motivated by the following statement in Hermann Weyl's [The Classical Groups](https://books.google.com/books?id=2twDDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA4#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> A poly­nomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ different zeros; this follows in the well-known way by proving that $f\left(x\right)$ contains the factors $\left(x — \alpha_1\right)\left(x — \alpha_2\right)\dots$ if $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots$ are distinct zeros.

I have sources which provide "advanced" proofs.  I am seeking an intuitively satisfying proof that could be presented to a reasonably intelligent high school student with the expectation of understanding.  I am more interested in the method of proof, than the proof itself.

Comment: The intuitively satisfying version (IMHO) is indeed the algorithm of factorizing: Find a root, divide by the corresponding linear factor, see that you get remainder zero, and repeat.

Comment: I believe I can provide a somewhat intuitive demonstration of this fact, but I do need to ask one question - are you familiar with complex numbers on some level? I ask, because the theorem "a polynomial of degree $n$ is the product of $n$ binomials" is analogous to the fundamental theorem of algebra, which is slightly different for real polynomials and complex polynomials. (Namely, real polynomials of degree $n$ have *at most* $n$ roots, and complex ones will have *exactly* $n$ roots.) It's a small but important nuance.

Comment: For the record, my demonstration indeed would have been the factoring idea T. Bongers mentioned lol

Comment: This is related to the fundamental theorem of algebra which has been proven many times, but never satisfactorily.

Answer (score 2):

> A poly­nomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ different zeros; this follows in the well-known way by proving that $f\left(x\right)$ contains the factors $\left(x — \alpha_1\right)\left(x — \alpha_2\right)\dots$ if $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots$ are distinct zeros.

This statement does *not* claim that a polynomial of degree $n$ can be expressed as the product of $n$ binomials.
In fact, the claim in the title of your question is **false** in real algebra, although it is true in complex algebra.

What the claim in the book actually asserts is that *if* the numbers
$\alpha_1,$ $\alpha_2, \ldots,$ $\alpha_k$ are $k$ distinct zeros of a polynomial $f(x),$ then
$$f(x) = (x - \alpha_1)(x - \alpha_2)\cdots(x - \alpha_k)g(x) \tag1$$
where $g(x)$ is a polynomial.
It never says that so many zeros necessarily exist.

A real polynomial of any even degree may have no real zeros at all. A real polynomial of any odd degree may have just one real zero and no others. In general, a polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $n$ can have fewer than $n$ zeros, but it cannot have *more* than $n$ zeros.
If it had more than $n$ zeros, the factorization in Equation $(1)$ would show that $f(x)$ was a polynomial of degree greater than $n,$ a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will have a basic algebraic proof, at a high school level, because you require complex numbers to even deal with $x^2+1$. Even [this](https://mathscholar.org/2018/09/simple-proofs-the-fundamental-theorem-of-algebra/) supposedly simple proof requires calculus.

Comment: I am reaching back more decades than I care to admit, but I vaguely recall that a demonstration was giving by my high school teacher.  We did learn the basics of complex numbers, so the proof may have involved complex numbers.  I believe explicit reference to complex numbers might be avoided by either expressing the problem in the language of linear algebra, or using the language of abstract algebra.  Note that I have refined the proposition to "...n or fewer binomials."

Comment: @StevenHatton I'm sure that really advanced high school students can follow the link I posted, but I am not personally comfortable calling that a "high-school level" proof. Maybe my own experience with students taking calculus in college has soured me to the American public education system, but truthfully I don't think you will find an average high schooler that will follow. On a different note, the link below appears to shed some light on the state of the art; some amount of analysis or topology is required for the proof. https://mathoverflow.net/a/25045